# the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used in if else statement

Tags: r

```
pred=data.frame(seq(1,100,by=2))
obs=data.frame(seq(1,100,by=3))
pr=data.frame(seq(1,200,by=4))
for (i in 1:dim(pred)[2]) {
  if (pr[,i]>max(pred[,i],na.rm=T)){
    pr[,i]=pr[,i]*(max(obs[,i],na.rm=T)/max(pred[,i],na.rm=T))}}
```

I am getting error"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" any alternatives??

Comment: You might be looking for `ifelse`

Comment: `ifelse` is the vectorized alternative to `if`. However, if you describe in words what you're trying to do there may be a better way.

Comment: I am working with climate data, if the values are above the threshold which i defined in the code, i want to multiply with a factor else i want to do quantile mapping. (I didn't wanted to put whole code as it may create confusion)

Comment: Have you looked at package qmap?

Comment: yes i did, i wanted to do quantile mapping only for the precipitation value below  some threshold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to multiply all values matching a condition with a factor. For your example it would be:

```
pred=data.frame(seq(1,100,by=2))
obs=data.frame(seq(1,100,by=3))
pr=data.frame(seq(1,200,by=4))
condition <- pr[,1] > max(pred[,1],na.rm=T)
#set NA values false
condition[is.na(condition)] <- F
fac <- max(obs[,1],na.rm=T)/max(pred[,1],na.rm=T)
pr[condition,1] <- pr[condition,1]*fac
#do other stuff if the condition is false
```

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I tried with the above script.. as my data has NA values ... I got a error saying "missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames"