# How to apply if statements when the condition is taken from a different dataframe, but with a common variable

Tags: r

I have a blank encounter history dataframe with all zeros. I want to fill it with the value '1' where there is an encounter in a specific year.

My data file (datafile) looks somewhat like this:

```
Date               Name
2007-04-28          a
2007-05-19          a
2007-05-21          b                
2008-04-28          a
2009-05-06          c
```

And the 'empty' data-frame (encounter) that has to be recoded

```
Name  2007   2008   2009   2010
a      0      0      0      0
b      0      0      0      0
c      0      0      0      0
d      0      0      0      0
e      0      0      0      0
```

I tried using an if statement:

```
datafile$Date%>%if(datafile$Date==between(01-01-07&31-12-07)) {encounter$2007=="1"}
```

But got an error

```
Error in between(1 - 1 - 7 & 31 - 12 - 7) : 
  between has been x of type logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (.) datafile$Date == between(1 - 1 - 7 & 31 - 12 - 7) else { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Try `table(format(as.Date(df1$Date), "%Y"), df1$Name)`

Comment: Whether you are using [`dplyr::between`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/between) or [`data.table::between`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.0/topics/between) (or some other?), please read the help docs for it: the function (both versions) takes three arguments, not one. From there, your warning about "condition length" is a frequent one on SO (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/34053043/3358272). Finally, `01-01-07` to R is negative seven, not a date as you might think; you should look into `as.Date`.

Comment: @akrun Thank you, but it's giving me the same error

Comment: @r2evans I'm using between() from dplyr, and for the date, I already converted to the format %d-%m-%y with datafile$Date<- as.Date(datafile$Date, format="%d-%m-%y")   Do you know what I could do? Really confused. Thanks!

Comment: You are using `if` and `between` incorrectly. Have you tried @akrun's suggested code?

Comment: @r2evans Thank you. I now looked them up, and used in combination with 
 akrun's code: table(format(as.Date(live$Datum), "%Y"), live$Ringnr) and then library(data.table)
live$Datum%>% if(between(live$Datum,2007-01-01,2007-12-31, incbounds=TRUE)){enc$y07=="1"} I'm now getting a result that everything is false. Btw my original two data frames are called 'live' and 'enc', and read 'Datum' for date. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @r2evans I used the transmute and tally functions with tidyr, and it worked great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you said you need. (Data all the way at the bottom.)

```r
library(dplyr)
datafile %>%
  transmute(Year = format(Date, "%Y"), Name) %>%
  xtabs(data = ., ~ Name + Year)
#     Year
# Name 2007 2008 2009
#    a    2    1    0
#    b    1    0    0
#    c    0    0    1
```

though that produces an object of class `"xtabs" "table"`, not a frame. For that you can use:

```r
library(tidyr)
encounters <- datafile %>%
  transmute(Year = format(Date, "%Y"), Name) %>%
  group_by(Year, Name) %>%
  tally() %>%
  tidyr::spread(Year, n) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Name), ~ replace(., is.na(.), 0))
encounters
# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#   Name  `2007` `2008` `2009`
#   <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 a          2      1      0
# 2 b          1      0      0
# 3 c          0      0      1
```

---

Some problems with your code.

I think you are intending to pass the `Date` column into `between`, so something like this might be closer to what you are trying to do:

```r
datafile$Date %>%
  between(as.Date("2007-01-01"), as.Date("2007-12-31"))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

But that doesn't help us assign a particular value. This doesn't immediately allow you to assign new values back into the frame, but at least I can help you fix your use of `between`.

Further, the `%>%` operator/function is passing data forward, it does not immediately allow assigning elsewhere. You can fake it, but I don't think it is how it was intended to work. And since this conditional vector is created from `datafile` (which is one "shape") and you want to assign values into `encounters` (which is a completely different "shape"), you will run into logical problems that are really best to avoid.

---

Data:

```r
datafile <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text='
Date               Name
2007-04-28          a
2007-05-19          a
2007-05-21          b                
2008-04-28          a
2009-05-06          c')
datafile$Date <- as.Date(datafile$Date)
```